# Spring Injection in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, dependency-injection, struts2

I have a jsp page which needs a java code.

This java code inside jsp needs a service class.

Now my service class is java gets created using spring DI and DAO & other things are injected in service class using Spring.

But when i want to use it in jsp, how should I ask spring to provide me the object of service inside jsp?

JSP -> Java Code -> Service -> DAO

I am using struts2 & spring DI as frameworks.

Comment: Really confused between who wants what. Please provide some code to avoid confusion.

Comment: if you trying to do this, must say you are not doing things fundamentally right.JSP is not meant for working with your Service layer or even with your S2 action classes

Comment: Well I know this is written wrong but I have to keep it working, may be in next release we plan to make it more standard :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a  class that is Spring-managed and application context aware. This class will provide Spring bean via static methods from anywhere in your code.

```
@Service
public class SpringBeansProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    static private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> type) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        applicationContext = context;
    }

}
```

From anywhere in your code, use `SpringBeansProvider.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class)`. Yes, this breaks down a concept of beans injection and mixes up static and non-static methods usage, but such kind of task always cause those unfair things.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. Any setting to be done for this class inside application context?

Comment: No, it's enough just to have this class bean in application context.

Answer (score 0):

You don't inject into JSP pages; you inject into the action class and access using normal S2 mechanisms.